# How do we get a drive by its label in PowerShell 5.0?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have an `autorun.inf` file with the following contents on my external hard drive:

```
[Autorun]
Label=MasterSword
```

This labels my external hard drive once it's plugged in as, `MasterSword`. I want to store a few scripts on it and include them in my `$profile` so they are loaded when PowerShell starts or when the profile is re-included (`. $profile`) at the interpreter.

As many know, using a hard-coded drive letter for external drives can lead to changing the reference to those external hard drive scripts every time the drive letter changes, resulting in the inclusion failing.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. How do I get a hold of the drive label that was set in the `autorun.inf`?
2. How do I translate that drive label into the drive letter so I can reference the scripts stored on it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did a little more research and came up with this little snippet:

To answer #1:

```
$scriptDrive = Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel MasterSword
```

To answer #2:

```
$scriptDriveLetter = $scriptDrive.DriveLetter
```

And together, they would be:

```
$scriptDrive = Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel MasterSword
$scriptDriveLetter = $scriptDrive.DriveLetter
```

Or for another interpretation:

```
$scriptDriveLetter = (Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel MasterSword).DriveLetter
```

Where the necessary drive letter is stored in `$scriptDriveLetter`.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq "MasterSword"}
```

This will return an object such as:

```
Name            : E
Description     : MasterSword
Provider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
Root            : E:\
CurrentLocation : Scripts
```

Thus, assuming your scripts are in the "Scripts" folder, you can find them with:

```
$Root = (Get-PSDrive | Where-Object {$_.Description -eq "MasterSword"}).Root
$Path = Join-Path $Root "Scripts"
```

Comment: This solution does not work. The labeled drive in the example does not have a description. Please use `$psdrive = Get-PSDrive` `$psdrive.Description` to test for yourself.

Comment: Ah yes, your own answer looks more accurate using `Get-Volume`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification to ExcellentSP's answer that I used for my own use.

I have the script look for the plugged in usb by name and change the drive letter to a pre-determined drive letter:

```
$scriptDrive = Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel "mastersword"
Get-Partition -DriveLetter ($scriptDrive.DriveLetter) | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter W
```

You can replace `-DriveLetter` with `-DriveNumber` as well dependent on your use.

But this was only because I was being lazy and didn't want to do much modifying my old script.

Most likely, the best way to do it is:

```
$scriptDrive = Get-Volume -FileSystemLabel "mastersword"
$drive = $scriptDrive.DriveLetter
```

You would then use $drive for any pathways or directories within this drive.
ex: `$drive:\folder\picture.jpg`